# Possibility of converting iPhone application to Android without changing source code?

Tags: android, iphone, apk, ipa, iphone-developer-program

I once saw a website that provides a service of converting IPA files to APK. Supposedly, you just install their SDK in Xcode. You don't need to port the code from Objective-C to Java.

But I cannot find it again. Does anyone know of such a site/service?

Comment: It's NOT converting IPA files to APK. It's recompile project sources with modified Android NDK. check their site, now it's beta.

Answer (score 1):

[Apportable](http://www.apportable.com/) offers to port iOS games to Android, but I've never used them myself.

Comment: Apportable provides an Objective-C platform that runs on the Android NDK, enabling IOS apps to be recompiled to run natively on Android. (I'm an engineer at Apportable)

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking to do the same here and I came across this site:
http://www.yeecco.com 
It offers a service to convert ipa files for Samsung store ready apps from what I can tell. 
But I haven't used it because it doesn't seem too legit what with its poor spelling and grammar.